The relationship and difference between plugins and elements in gstreamer?
In learning GStreamer, I encountered a problem: I don't quite understand the difference between the concepts of plugin and element. When I use gst-inspect-1.0 to inspect plugins, I find that plugins are all derived from a particular element. Does this mean that a plugin is essentially the same as an element?

A plugin usually contains one or more elements.

If a plugin contains only one element, would it be correct to consider these two concepts as equivalent, if you don't mind me asking?

No, a plugin merely just holds information to elements or other functionality.

Thank you for your explanation, I understand now.
